# SpringToolSuit can not open on macbook m1

Tags: macos, spring-tool-suite

When I open the application SrpingtoolSuite always displays the message "springtoolsuite4 can't be opened"

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me. Try this code to terminal

codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app

Answer (score 0):

It seems the signature of the sts got tempered while updating the JDK version or any other application which might affect STS.
To verify whether the STS signature tempered.

Run the command in terminal:

`codesign -v -vvv --deep /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app`

if the result of above command is something like -

`/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app: invalid Info.plist (plist or signature have been modified)`

then definitely there is some issue related to signature only.
To fix the issue:

Run:
`sudo codesign --force --sign - /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app`